# how to do animate line chart in flex like fusion charts

Tags: apache-flex, linechart

I am working on line-chart in flex. I could not find any way of animating it just like the line-chart in a fusion chart.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of info available:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/10/15/using-data-effects-to-animate-chart-data/
http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/06/03/save-a-snapshot-image-of-a-flex-app-without-a-server/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681969/how-to-animate-the-flex-chart-axis-when-the-maximum-of-the-data-changes

Comment: In the first link it shows the example of barcharts. Second and third links also donot show the animation of linecharts

Comment: The process will be v similar.